# Design Review Of SOLID Principles For An Autonomous Mobile Robot

Tags: c++, solid, robotics

I am self-learning robotics, C++ and good object oriented design.  I have asked various questions over the past couple of weeks: [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390364/re-usability-in-c-using-interfaces-and-external-configuration) and [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390274/would-de-coupling-using-interfaces-templates-make-the-system-easier-to-maintain) that have lead to the following design.

The design goal is for portability.  It is a *Go-To-Goal* [Differential Drive Robot](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/robotics_sg/Control/kinematics/unicycle.html) with PID to regulate the behavior.

I am hoping my design is robust enough so that once I have more understanding of dynamic vehicle models, that I can simply plug those in without modifications ; the O in SOLID :)

**please note I have not compiled this code yet, I am not looking for a syntax check, just rough design review**

The **state** of the robot is represented as follow:

```
struct SensorConfig {
  // required config values
};

class Sensor {

  public:
  virtual ~Sensor() = default;

  // basic checks to ensure sensor is still
  // functioning correctly
  virtual bool IsActive() = 0;

  // 
  virtual void Init(const SensorConfig& config) = 0;


  virtual vector<double> const ReadMeasurement() = 0;


};

class State {

 public:

  virtual ~State() = default;

  virtual void Update(const vector<double> values) = 0;
  virtual void Update(const vector<Sensor>& sensors) = 0;

  // overloading the operator so that I can measure
  // the error between target state and current state
  // each model can have its own way of deciding how to do that
  virtual vector<double> operator- const (const State& state) = 0;

};

class UnicycleModel : public State {

 public:
  UnicyleModel(double velocity, double omega, double wheel_radius, double distance_between_wheels);

  virtual void Update(vector<Sensor>& sensors)
  {
    if (sensors.size() < 2)
      {
    // FAIL with error message
      }
    Sensor r_wheel_odometry = sensors.at(0);
    Sensor l_wheel_odometry = sensors.at(1);

    double r_rotation_rate = r_wheel_odometry.ReadMeasurement().at(0);
    double l_rotation_rate = r_wheel_odometry.ReadMeasurement().at(0);

    // apply unicyle model equations to
    // set velocity_ and omega_;

  };

  // just an example
  virtual vector<double> operator- const (const State& state)
  {
    // example
    return vector{state.omega - this->omega_, state.velocity - this->velocity};
  }

 private:
  double velocity_;
  double omega_;
  double wheel_radius;
  double distance_between_wheels_;


};

class LongitudinalDynamicsModel : public State {

  public:
  LongitudinalDynamicsModel(double velocity, double theta, double phi, // etc);

  virtual void Update(vector<Sensor>& sensors)
  {

    // apply vehicle dynamics equations to
    // set state;

  };

  virtual vector<double> operator- const (const State& state)
  {
    // example
    return vector{state.velocity - this->velocity, //etc};
  }
 private:
  // state representation
};

class LatDynamicsModel : public State {

  public:
  LatDynamicsModel(double velocity, double theta, double phi, // etc);

  virtual void Update(vector<Sensor>& sensors)
  {

    // apply vehicle dynamics equations to
    // set state;

  };

  virtual vector<double> operator- const (const State& state)
  {
    // example
    return vector{state.velocity - this->velocity, //etc};
  }
 private:
  // state representation
};
```

The **go-to-goal** behavior is represented as

```
class PID {

 public:
  virtual ~PID() = default;

  virtual State const CalculateError(const State& target_state, const State& current_state) = 0;

  virtual void SetProportionalGain(const double& kp) = 0;
  virtual void SetIntegralGain(const double& ki) = 0;
  virtual void SetDifferentialGain(const double& kd) = 0;

};

class Actuator {

 public:
  virtual ~Actuator() = default;

  virtual bool Apply(const State& error) = 0;
};

class Motor {
 pubic:
  Motor(Pwm speed_pin, Ouput control_a, Output control_b);

  inline bool Start();
  inline bool Stop();
  inline bool SpinForward();
  inline bool SpinBackward();

};

class UniCycleDriver : public Actuator {

 public:
  UniCycleDriver(Motor& right_motor, Motor& left_motor);

  virtual bool Apply(const State& error) {

  };

  inline bool Start();
  inline bool Stop();
  inline bool DriveForward();
  inline bool DriveBackward();

  inline const bool IsDrivnigForward();

 private:
  bool is_driving_forward_;
  Motor right_motor_;
  Motor left_motor_;

};

class FrontWheelDriver : public Actuator {

  public:

  virtual bool Apply(const State& error) {

  };

};
```

Then finally, the **main** part of the system, where the control loops will take place

```
// this class should be instantiated in main along with calls to factories required to instantiate the sensors, states, etc..
class ControlAgent {

  // set target state
  // measure current state
  // calculate error
  // apply error

 public:
  ControlAgent(const vector<Sensor>& sensors,
           PID& regulator,
           Actuator& actuator);

  void SetTargetState(const State& state);

  void ClosedLoop()
  {
    State error = regulator.CalculateError(target_state_, current_state_);

    while (target - error > some_threshold)
      {
        actuator.Apply(error);
        current_state_.Update(sensors);
        error = regulator.CalculateError(target_state_, current_state_);    
      }
  };
 private:
  State current_state_;
  State target_state_;

};
```

Comment: Once you have compiled, tested, and debugged it, I recommend going to  [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and asking for help there. Just keep in mind that the code has to actually work before it can be reviewed.

Comment: @user1118321 I think that Sam is looking for a design review before implementing anything in the wrong direction. The only code (apart from the interface definition) is to illustrate how the interface will be used. The snippets are basically only like a textual class diagram.

Comment: And I'm saying that once he *has* implemented it, he can get further help and learn even more by doing a code review of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This already seems like a very good [SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) start. At first sight:

- Open/Closed seems there through proper extensible classes with a well defined API.
- Interface segregation seems there as well, with a very simple, purpose oriented interface.
- Dependency inversion is nicely done in your agent.

However, there are the following flaws:

- Liskov Substitution Principle is not fulfilled, because if I replace a a `UnicycleState` with a `LongitudinalModelState`, your bot will not work anymore because the vector of values will be interpreted differently. Moreover your bot would not notice the problem and get crazy.
- Single Responsibility Principle is not given either. The SRP is not about what the classes do (here you’re fine) but about the reason to change. And here, there seems to be a hidden coupling (revealed by the naming, confirmed by the use of the state values) between some States and some Actuators.

My advice would be to replace the vector of values (expected in a precise order) with either an `unordered_map` that can find specific types of measurements, but with a typology shared between all the relevant classes (for example an enum to say what kind of value is meant). The interpretation of the values would then be more robust. And if one actuator does’t find a type of value it is looking for, it could at least complain.

I would then advise you to go on, in order to avoid staying stuck in pursuit of a perfect design, or end up with over-engineering. With your design and the proposed map, you’d have a sufficiently robust base. You may later still refactor if necessary.

Comment: @Christohpe The ordered_map is exactly what I needed and just didn't think of.  I wasn't sure how to give the values `meaning` and of course an ordered map will do that.  Thanks again! I think I will continue on with implementation now,it's been a nice crash course into OOD!